# DotNetZip System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path is denied

Tags: c#, dotnetzip

I know here is some questions about this error in DotNetZip, I've tried all solutions and failed. I'm developing code on my Win8.1 notebook and have no problems, problems begin after deploy to the remote Win2008R2 server...

Here is the problem method:

```
public bool CreateZIP(string ListStep)
{
    Logger logger = LogManager.GetLogger("Task:CreateZIP" + this.TaskGuid);

    using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
    {
        zip.AlternateEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("cp866");
        zip.AlternateEncodingUsage = Ionic.Zip.ZipOption.Always;

        ...
        zip.AddFile(...) loop
        ...

        zip.MaxOutputSegmentSize = Properties.Settings.Default.ZIPSizeLimit * 1024 * 1024;

        string zipFolder = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), @"zip-tmp");
        string TaskZipFolder = Path.Combine(zipFolder, this.TaskGuid);

        try
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(zipFolder)) Directory.CreateDirectory(zipFolder);
            if (!Directory.Exists(TaskZipFolder)) Directory.CreateDirectory(TaskZipFolder);

            zip.TempFileFolder = Path.GetTempPath();
            zip.Save(Path.Combine(TaskZipFolder, this.TaskGuid + @".zip"));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            logger.Fatal("Unable to save ZIP into ({0}): {1}", Path.Combine(TaskZipFolder, this.TaskGuid + @".zip"), e.ToString());
            throw;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

This code is running on remote server from domain user `gfo-svc` from `C:\Courier\WD` directory.
Each object instance has it's GUID, for example `e1664582-1bbc-4a9f-a9fe-e7ce4a0a8a55`
So the `zipFolder` variable value is `C:\Courier\WD\zip-tmp` and `TaskZipFolder` value is `C:\Courier\WD\zip-tmp\e1664582-1bbc-4a9f-a9fe-e7ce4a0a8a55`

When this code tries to run it fails with this stack trace:

```
Unable to save ZIP into (C:\Courier\WD\zip-tmp\e1664582-1bbc-4a9f-a9fe-e7ce4a0a8a55\e1664582-1bbc-4a9f-a9fe-e7ce4a0a8a55.zip): System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path is denied.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError()
   at System.IO.File.InternalMove(String sourceFileName, String destFileName, Boolean checkHost)
   at Ionic.Zip.ZipSegmentedStream.TruncateBackward(UInt32 diskNumber, Int64 offset)
   at Ionic.Zip.ZipEntry.Write(Stream s)
   at Ionic.Zip.ZipFile.Save()
   at Ionic.Zip.ZipFile.Save(String fileName)
   at Worker.Task.CreateZIP(String ListStep) in Worker.cs:line 844
```

Line 844 contains this code: `zip.Save(Path.Combine(TaskZipFolder, this.TaskGuid + @".zip"));`

But in the `C:\Courier\WD\zip-tmp\e1664582-1bbc-4a9f-a9fe-e7ce4a0a8a55` folder I can see file `e1664582-1bbc-4a9f-a9fe-e7ce4a0a8a55.z01`, so the first part of archive was saved before failure.

`gfo-svc` user has ownership on `C:\Courier\WD` directory and my code could create `zip-tmp` directory if it is not exists, and GUID-named directory in it. So the problem is not in Windows Security permissions.
UAC on this remote server is disabled.

What could I do wrong? What might be wrong with my environment? What could I do?

Comment: "So the problem is not in Windows Security permissions." The message says otherwise. Simplify the testcase to `File.WriteAllText(path, "")`. This has nothing to do with zip.; Use procmon on the server to observe the exact failure as returned by the Windows Kernel. It will probably say ACCESS_DENIED or something.

Comment: @usr `File.WriteAllText()` worked fine with no errors. In procmon there is one ACESS_DENIED message, but I can't understand where it comes from...

Comment: Well, what does the path next to ACCESS_DENIED say? Is it the exact zip file path?

Comment: Note, that the error occured when `File.InternalMove` was running. THe zip lib moved the file. Maybe destination access was denied.

Comment: @usr this is what procmon says about ACCESS DENIED message: `Date & Time: 3/11/2014 4:40:41 PM
Event Class: File System
Operation: CreateFile
Result: ACCESS DENIED
Path: C:\Windows\SysWOW64
TID: 3388
Duration: 0.0000260
Desired Access: Write Data/Add File, Synchronize
Disposition: Open
Options: 
Attributes: n/a
ShareMode: Read, Write
AllocationSize: n/a`

Comment: What about the accesses to the zip file and temp path? Are they all SUCCESS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, here is the reason:
This code runs twice on the same host: first time manually from cmd and second time from Windows Task Scheduler.
By default, Task Scheduler starts tasks from C:\windows\system32 and process could not write into it. But my code tried to write into relative to working directory path, so in fact it was trying to write into ...\system32\tmp-dir.